# JQuery - write conditional when object property is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I'm trying to write a conditional for when an object property's value is blank, but it is not triggering. This is my code. Any idea how I should write this?

```
console.log(vid);
if (vid.video == undefined){
  //DO STUFF HERE - Doesn't work
}
```

The "object" in the screenshot is referenced in the code above as variable vid. I also tried undefined in the conditional.

[image]

Comment: `vid.video` _is_ an empty string so your conditional will never be satisfied. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some misunderstading here:

You say `when an object property's value is blank` but your coded `if (vid.video != ""){`.

I think you need `if (!vid.video) {`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
vid.video == undefined
```

Also what Andrew said. If you want to DO STUFF when the attribute is empty, you should Use "==", and not "!="

Answer (score 0):

```
if(vid.video != "")
```

Are you looking to only execute code when video doesn't equal "" but if you want to execute code when it is equal to "" you need

```
if(vid.video == "")
```

However if you want to check to see if its undefined you'll need to do

```
if(vid.video === undefined){
  vid.video is not defined here
}
```

or

```
if(vid.video){
  vid.video is defined here
}
```